# Calculate Probability of Winning Draw

Tags: probability

If there is a draw each month with 3 prizes, a entrant can only win one of the prizes each month but all entrants will be in the next months draw. There are 120 entrants. What is the probability of winning 1 prize in the year? What process would I go through to answer this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the inverse probability:
You can calculate the probability that an entrant doesn't win a prize in $12$ months. The probability is: 
$$\frac {119^{12}}{120^{12}}\cdot \frac {118^{12}}{119^{12}}\cdot \frac {117^{12}}{118^{12}}$$ and then you can use the inverse probability $$1-\frac {119^{12}}{120^{12}}\cdot \frac {118^{12}}{119^{12}}\cdot \frac {117^{12}}{118^{12}}$$. Indeed the probability that an entrant doesn't win a prize in a draw is:$$\frac {119}{120}\cdot \frac {118}{119}\cdot \frac {117}{118}$$ The my first answer was wrong but this I think  be right

Comment: Initially this looked correct to me but on greater inspection this doesn't seem to make sense, because probability are in the range 0 and 1. If the draw was ran fro 5 years (60 months) gives 1.51 (151%) probability this doesn't make sense.

Comment: You can use the inverse probability now I edit

Comment: I edited my answer I think that this answer is right

Comment: @Dean have you seen my edit?

Comment: YEs thanks for the edit.